# How to mock KeyguardManager

Tags: java, android, easymock

I'm trying to write a test for the `isKeyguardSecure()` method of the `KeyguardManager` class.

When I attempt to create a mock object using `EasyMock` with the line:

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManagerMock = EasyMock.createMock(KeyguardManager.class);
```

I receive the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.app.KeyguardManager is not an interface
```

Any ideas on how to properly create a mock of the `KeyguardManager` class?

Comment: I believe it's final so it can't be subclassed. Create a wrapper class around it and mock that class.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine but I think you are using a really old version of EasyMock. So you need the class extension to mock a class.

Can you please try EasyMock 3+ ? It should work right away